# How to compare negative value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have developed an application where user will enter numeric values. The values entered by user will be negative or positive both. I have entered correct answer in database in range e.g. (-80~-90). When user enter positive value then it is working fine but every time for negative values below condition giving wrong output. How can I resolve this ?

```
IF ABS(value1) < ABS(min1) AND ABS(value1) > ABS(max1) AND  (lower(severity1) = lower('Severe-1') OR lower(severity1) = lower('Critical'))
    THEN
    update audit_ques_link SET line_stop = 0 where audit_question_id IN(SELECT max(audit_question_id) FROM audit_ques_link);
    RETURN QUERY Select cast(0 as numeric) as msg,cast('Stop line' as character varying), am.audit_id, ddl8.dd_value  as stageno,
        ddl1.dd_value as stage, ddl2.dd_value, ddl3.activity_id as activity_id, ddl4.dd_value as activity, 
        ddl5.dd_value as process, ddl3.product as product, ddl3.assembly as assembly, ddl6.dd_value as line_no,
        ddl7.dd_value as area
        from audit_ques_detail am 
        left join dd_type_details ddl1 on ddl1.dd_id= am.stage
        left join dd_type_details ddl2 on ddl2.dd_id= am.stage_no
        left join audit_master ddl3 on ddl3.audit_id= am.audit_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl4 on ddl4.dd_id= ddl3.activity_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl5 on ddl5.dd_id = ddl3.process
        left join dd_type_details ddl6 on ddl6.dd_id = ddl3.line_no
        left join dd_type_details ddl7 on ddl7.dd_id = ddl3.area
        left join dd_type_details ddl8 on ddl8.dd_id =  am.stage_no
        where audit_ques_id = (select question_id from audit_ques_link  order by audit_question_id desc limit 1);
    ELSE

    IF ABS(value1) < ABS(min1) OR ABS(value1) > ABS(max1)
    THEN
    update audit_ques_link SET isCorrect = 0 where audit_question_id IN(SELECT max(audit_question_id) FROM audit_ques_link);
    ELSe
    update audit_ques_link SET isCorrect = 1 where audit_question_id IN(SELECT max(audit_question_id) FROM audit_ques_link);
    END IF;

    update audit_ques_link SET line_stop = 1 where audit_question_id IN(SELECT max(audit_question_id) FROM audit_ques_link);
    RETURN QUERY Select cast(1 as numeric) as msg,cast('Correct answer' as character varying), am.audit_id, ddl8.dd_value  as stageno,
        ddl1.dd_value as stage, ddl2.dd_value, ddl3.activity_id as activity_id, ddl4.dd_value as activity, 
        ddl5.dd_value as process, ddl3.product as product, ddl3.assembly as assembly, ddl6.dd_value as line_no,
        ddl7.dd_value as area
        from audit_ques_detail am 
        left join dd_type_details ddl1 on ddl1.dd_id= am.stage
        left join dd_type_details ddl2 on ddl2.dd_id= am.stage_no
        left join audit_master ddl3 on ddl3.audit_id= am.audit_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl4 on ddl4.dd_id= ddl3.activity_id
        left join dd_type_details ddl5 on ddl5.dd_id = ddl3.process
        left join dd_type_details ddl6 on ddl6.dd_id = ddl3.line_no
        left join dd_type_details ddl7 on ddl7.dd_id = ddl3.area
        left join dd_type_details ddl8 on ddl8.dd_id =  am.stage_no
        where audit_ques_id = (select question_id from audit_ques_link  order by audit_question_id desc limit 1);
    END IF;
```

Below is the meaning of Variables.

```
Values stored in database = -80~-90
value for min1 is -80
value for max1 is -90
Suppose if user entered -85 then I want to check if -85 is in range or not.
```

Comment: That needs some clarification what the code is supposed to do and what the variables mean.

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: Surely your range is back to front?  If your range goes from -85 to -90 then -90 is the minimum value, and -85 is the maximum value.

Comment: Your code still doesn't make any sense to me. What keeps you from simply running `IF value1 BETWEEN min1 AND max1 THEN /* something */ END IF;`? Please don't clarify that with a comment, but by editing the questions. What are all these updates and selects supposed to accomplish? Perhaps the best solution would be to remove everything that is unrelated to the question from the code so that you have a minimal code sample.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `-80` is grater then `-90` so `min` `max` may reverse but let's continue with your value

Example :

```
value1=-85
min1=-80
max1=-90
```

Now If you want check `value1` is in range or not then your condition may be:

```
If ABS(value1) >= ABS(min1) AND ABS(value1) <= ABS(max1)
```